# Symfony Redirecting User to Home Page using Nginx

Tags: symfony, nginx

This is probably be more related to nginx configuration than Symfony, but I am pretty sure a symfony developer might know the answer to this question

```
server {
server_name dev.some.com;
root /var/www/some/web;

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
    try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
}

proxy_buffer_size    128k;
proxy_buffers     4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;

# DEV
# This rule should only be placed on your development environment
# In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

This is the nginx configuration for the virtualhost. Our website's home page accessed at 'dev.some.com/main'. So, I want to configure nginx so that if there is no parameters passed, then it should forward the user to /main.

I've tried few rewrite rules, but no luck. Any idea ?